# Convert matlab fig into csv, txt or ascii

Tags: matlab, csv

I have the m-file on generating all the graphs in .fig I need with a for loop, but I don't know how to extract the array data to csv, txt or ascii format (16-bit).

```
imagesc(x,y,C);  %C is the data I want to extract
%m and n are variables created inside the for loop
```

I have tried dlmwrite and save, but I failed and could not fix the problem.

So I want to convert fig into csv, txt or ascii format instead.

```
filename_B=strcat(MM,'_profile');  %MM is a variable created inside the for loop
dlmwrite(filename_B.txt,squeeze(Data_time(:,m,n,:)),'');  %Data_time is C
save(filename_B, squeeze(Data_time(:,m,n,:)),'-ascii','-double');
```

I have also tried csvwrite

```
filename_B=strcat(MM,'_profile');
csvwrite(filename_B.txt, squeeze(Data_time(:,m,n,:)));
```

but there is an error message, "??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array."

It would be better if I could just extract the data directly to the desirable format without first producing fig then convert.

For confidential issue, I can't provide the whole script, but I will try my best to explain my problem.

Many thanks!

Comment: ok, one thing at a time. You definitely need to use only `dlmwrite`, it is way easier than extracting data from a `.fig` file. Can you edit your question to show the problem (exact error message for instance) with `dlmwrite` only ?

Comment: Do you have a field txt in the structure filename_B ?

Comment: When you write `filename_B.txt` Matlab thinks you are looking for a [`structure`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) field named `txt`, which doesn't exist (because `filename_B` is a [`string`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html), not a `structure`). Try : `filename_B=strcat(MM,'_profile.txt');` ... and then `dlmwrite(filename_B, ... );`